# Log on to Winshuttle studio

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to log in to Winshuttle using VBA? (Manually, we would typically click this icon to activate it.)

[image]

I can successfully execute the code below after manually activating it. So, if I can find the correct line to automatically activate this login, my issue will be resolved.

```
Sub RunWinshuttleScript_BasicView() 'Firstrow, Lastrow
    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim StudioMacrosAddin As COMAddIn
    Dim StudioMacros As Object
    Dim strShuttleFile As String

    ' Specify the name of the Winshuttle Studio Macros add-in
    Const addInName As String = "WinshuttleStudioMacros.AddinModule"

    ' Get the Winshuttle Studio Macros add-in object from Outlook
    Set StudioMacrosAddin = Application.COMAddIns.Item(addInName)
    If StudioMacrosAddin Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to find the Winshuttle Studio Macros add-in."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Get the Winshuttle Studio Macros COM object from the add-in
    Set StudioMacros = StudioMacrosAddin.Object.Macros
    If StudioMacros Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to initialize the Winshuttle Studio Macros COM object."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    StudioMacros.StartRow = 9 'Firstrow
    StudioMacros.EndRow = 0 ' Run until the last row of data
    StudioMacros.WriteHeader = True ' Set to True to write headers during the run
    StudioMacros.RunReason = "Run Reason"
    StudioMacros.RunType = 0 ' Normal run type
    strShuttleFile = "C:\Users\E0709874\Desktop\Outlook_Attachment\winshuttle BPI\WS_scripts\MM01_BASICDATA_M2C_R2_EU.Txr"
    StudioMacros.AlfName = "R31-E0709874-100"
    ' Open the script
    StudioMacros.OpenScript strShuttleFile
    
    ' Run the script
    StudioMacros.RunScript
    Dim targetCell As Range
 
    Exit Sub

'ErrHandler:
    'MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```